# node.js handling variable undefined error through middleware

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js express app, and i'd like to catch any

```
<variable> is not defined
```

or

```
<object> does not have property <propertyname>
```

When i run the project locally, and a programmable error occurs I get these messages in the console and the request gets disposed. I want to handle them in the winston logger  instead.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to avoid `is not defined` errors, you need to use code lints like eslint. But I'm curious to know, why do you want to log it during run time instead of fixing it earlier?

Comment: it's not syntax errors, it's more like the object received from the database doesn't have the expected property. so it's runtime error. e.g. division by zero

Comment: Have you considered express's default [Error-handling middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling) for catching such errors

Comment: yeah, i have this pattern already  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
}); but var x = 5/0; does not trip this code

Comment: Is your error-handling middleware defined last? Can you post code samples of it?

Comment: I've posted app.js here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f6c3d63e5a9d9e0d09852f0e96953023

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130654/discussion-between-sridhar-and-melgamal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing dependencies from your code and testing with minimum reproducible snippet seem to work for me.

**Update**
Unhandled rejections can be handled using `unhandledRejection`

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path');

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
    console.log('uncaught exception', err);
}).on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.log('unhandledRejections reason', reason);
}).on('warning', (warning) => {
    console.log(`warning, ... ${warning}`);
});

var app = express();
app.use('/api/subscriber', (req, res) => {
    console.log('inside API');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      console.log(undeclaredVariable); // should error
      res.status(200).send({
          msg: 'hello world'
      });        
    });
});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next)  {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);   // Listen for requests
```

It logs

```
inside API
unhandledRejections reason [ReferenceError: undeclaredVariable is not defined]
```

Comment: hmm i think i found the issue. it appears that error handler snippet doesn't get invoked if the exception occured in an async operation e.g. MSSQLObject.execute(query).then( (results) => {  console.log(undefinedvariable) })

Comment: but if i have an error inside the router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) { console.log(undefinedvariable); }); this will invoke the error handlar callback

Comment: You should consider re-throwing the error in `uncaughtException` and allowing your app to crash. Then, have `forever`, Passenger, Kubernetes, or whatever restart your app.